# Reference section and citation call-out formatting, revtex4 document class

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

doing my 1st revtex article, used an example template to get going, but the format I want for my References section eludes me.  I have:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prb]{revtex4}   % prb is Physics Review B
\usepackage{amsmath}    % need for subequations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
```

At the end I have:

```
\section{Conclusion}

 There are articles that would be missed if only one or two databases/sources were searched

\appendix   
\section*{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{31}
\bibitem{1}
D Baye and P-H Heenen,
J. Phys. A:Math. Gen., \textbf{19} , 2041-2059 (1986).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I suspect from the comments, I have not got the right commands for the References section , and will probably might fix the issues below.  ('prb' is Physics Review B) Please suggest some basic changes I might make for a better bibliography?  I inherited what I have at the moment.

1) How do I make the  'REFERENCES' title start on a new line, AFTER the centred line that revtext puts.
Update:  I had added more material, the article expanded onto a new page - and the References title was now in the correct place.

2) How can I get the bibitem numbering to be formatted like in square brackets, normal character format?  (The prb standards I found say they should be in square brackets.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you plan to submit this article your changes will be probably rejected

Comment: And if you don't, there are easier classes to customise than this one.... Publishers' classes are not designed to allow customisation. They are designed to prevent it by imposing a consistent style on all authors.

Comment: I appreciate that understanding for publisher classes, this is just an assignment but I'd like to get it right.  I think the way my References section looks seems to be different from other prb References sections I have seen.

Comment: I think I should regardless be able to get the 'References' title to appear AFTER the line?

prb guidelines say: References and footnotes to text material must be combined in a single list, numbered consecutively in their order of first appearance in the paper. They should be designated and cited in text by on-line Arabic numerals in square brackets

I don't know how to get 'on-line Arabic numerals in square brackets'?

Also the [byrevtex] should work regardless of the class?

Comment: Please give us a complete minimal document which we can compile to produce the output you are currently getting which you want help with. What is 'prb'? If you are using `revtex4.cls` then it expects you to use `natbib` with a `.bib` file and BibTeX to produce the bibliography and citations. You are currently formatting the bibliography by hand so the intended format will not be applied. But you would be far better to use a more standard class if you don't actually want `revtex4` format anyway.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, my questions are well answered.  Just out of interest though, section"References and footnotes" at https://journals.aps.org/prb/info/infoB.html is where I got the 'Arabic numerals in square brackets" from; so the 2 different sources for prb disagree on that, maybe one is out of date ....

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How do I make the 'REFERENCES' title start on a new line, AFTER the centred line?

You don't. As you've noticed, `revtex4` style inserts a short horizontal rule immediately ahead of the bibliography and does not provide a separate header (such as "REFERENCES"). If you need to use the `revtex4` document class, do not modify this very basic and distinctive document layout feature.

> 2) How can I get the bibitem numbering to be formatted like in square brackets, normal character format? (The prb standards I found say they should be in square brackets)

The `revtex4` document class automatically loads the `natbib` package. Thus, inserting the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,square}
```

in the preamble will give you non-superscript numbers encased in square brackets.

That said, you should seriously reconsider whether you really have to change the citation call-out style. On page 110 of the user guide of `revtex4` class, under section 28.4.2, "prb", one finds:

> PRB requires superscript citations.

Thus, if you provide the `prb` option to the `\documentclass` instruction, you should almost certainly *not* change the citation call-out style to plain-numbers-encased-in-brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prb]{revtex4}   % prb is Physics Review B
\usepackage{amsmath}    % need for subequations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % no need to provide 'pdftex' option

\setcitestyle{numbers,square} % do reconsider whether this is necessary or advisable

\begin{document}

\section{Conclusion}

There are articles that would be missed if only one or two databases\slash sources were searched.\cite{1}

%%\appendix   
%%\section*{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{1}
D Baye and P-H Heenen,
J.\ Phys. A:Math.\ Gen., \textbf{19}, 2041--2059 (1986).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```